# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

In my view controller I call with a reference to game, which is an istance of Game class

```
score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [game score]];
```

Game has this:

```
int score
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int *score ;
```

son normally score has a getter.
Game.h is included in ViewController.h

Why do I get "unrecognized selector sent to instance"?

Comment: what does the error say specifically? i suspect you have released game or not assigned it correctly. Edit: see my answer as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you synthesize it in your implementation?

```
@synthesize score;
```

Also, you do not want a pointer to an int, but an int itself. Remove the '*'.

Thirdly, I'm assuming `score.text` is setting the text for a `UILabel` or similar? And is different from Game's `score`.

Another check you can use is to make use of dot-notation. If the property is not properly set, you will get an error rather than a warning. I.e. `game.score` instead of `[game score]`.

Comment: Yes, all is done and as you suggested I modified the label's name which was the same as the score proprety. now it is scoreLabel. But I got the same problem

Answer (score 1):

score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [game score]];//u can use %i instead %d

int score

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int score ;//remove here ur star

or

@property (nonatomic) int score ;//remove here ur star

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if thats a typo, but the property declaration of score doesn't need an asterisk, as its a primitive type, so that could definitely be the issue.